# How to react to a button click in pyqt5

Tags: python, connect, pyqt5

So, I am new to python programming. I have started to implement a UI in pyqt5 and there I have a button and I want to react when the user clicks it.

According to [this Link](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/) I should simply write `btn.clicked.connect(self.buton_pressed)` however I get the message "Cannot find reference connect in function". (The surrounding code is at the end of the question)

So I googled a bit and all I found is that it should just work that way. I just don't get why it does not. I found this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131569/pyqt-no-button-clicked-connect-function) which also describes the old variant of how to do it. That did not work either, after some googeling I found out that it is no longer supported in pyqt5 or in some other package.

The function where I try to connec to the event:

```
def __add_button(self, text: str, layout: QLayout):
    btn = QPushButton(text, self)
    layout.addWidget(btn)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)
    # TODO: fix this.
    return btn
```

The code where the GUI is generated and the function called, in the `__init__` function

```
lblhm = QLabel("Hauptmessung", self)
layout.addWidget(lblhm)

self.__hm_b = self.__add_button("Messung öffnen", layout)
self.__hm_config_b = self.__add_button("Configruation öffnen", layout)

lblzm = QLabel("Zusatzmessung", self)
layout.addWidget(lblzm)

self.__zm_b = self.__add_button("Messung öffnen", layout)
self.__zm_config_b = self.__add_button("Configuration öffnen", layout)
```

The button_pressed function is not yet implemented, but it is supposed to open a openFile dialog for file selection.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372402/pyqt4-timer-timeout-connect-cannot-find-reference) i could just connect after returning the function, but then i would have to write it 4 times which is not very nice. Isn't the signal bound to the object not to the variable?

Thankful for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 - timer.timeout.connect() - cannot find reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372402/pyqt4-timer-timeout-connect-cannot-find-reference)

Comment: Can you provide all your code so we can see where the function is located and how it's being used?

Comment: It is similar to that other question, problem is i can't simply assign it to an instance variable in that function as i call it multiple times. Only when it is  returned i assign it. Added that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to understand your problem since you don't provide us with a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a peace of code one can run "as is". Something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lblhm = QtGui.QLabel("Hauptmessung", self)
        layout.addWidget(lblhm)

        self.__hm_b = self.__add_button("Messung öffnen", layout)
        self.__hm_config_b = self.__add_button("Configruation öffnen", layout)

        lblzm = QtGui.QLabel("Zusatzmessung", self)
        layout.addWidget(lblzm)

        self.__zm_b = self.__add_button("Messung öffnen", layout)
        self.__zm_config_b = self.__add_button("Configuration öffnen", layout)

    def button_pressed(self):
        print('Button pressed')

    def __add_button(self, text: str, layout: QtGui.QLayout):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton(text, self)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.button_pressed)
        return btn



if __name__== '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = MyWindow()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There's no problem with this code under `PyQt4`. Does it work for with `PyQt5`?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the code. I tried it and it worked. However PyCharm still showed the error and i could not see the difference. So i decided to go the long way and actually try my code from the command line. And surprise, it worked. So the problem was PyCharm showing an error that did not exist. That is something that I, coming from eclipse and java programming, would have never thought possible. There an eclipse error always means an java error.
Thank you for your code. It may not be a solution to the pyCharm problem, but it solved my problem, so i will mark it as correct.